# use jquery UI theme in custom toolbar

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I want to use the jquery UI theme in my own toolbar without using jquery itself.

I have:

```
<div class="toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
  <a href="#" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circlesmall-close">close</a>
  <a href="#" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circlesmall-plus">open</a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.toolbar {
    height:28px;
}
    .toolbar a {
        display:inline-block;
        height:24px;
        width:24px;
    }
```

It works but when I set a padding or size on the a hrefs I don't get a nice centered icon on the button because it displays the icon and part of the surrounding icons in the icon file.

Is it possible to correct this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a margin instead of padding. This would keep the icons centred.

```
.toolbar {
    height:28px;
}
.toolbar a {
    display:inline-block;
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
    margin:6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/

It looks it needs a separate span of the right size to prevent the icon file displaying surrounding icons (sprites).